# Dynamically generate select menu options for each unselected item in an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I have an options field where I use to add "hours" and this field is doubled when I want to add other "hours" and I need to work like this:

```
Option Field 1: [0:00, 1:00, 2:00, 3:00, 5:00]
```

I select the `radio field = 1 [3:00]`

and when I add one more option field with "hours" I need to run out the value that has already been chosen in the first and so on.

```
Option Field 2: [0:00, 1:00, 2:00, 5:00]
```

My HTML is:

```
<select type="text" name="product[portion]" ng-model="formAddProduct.portions[i].label">
  <option value=""> Portion </option>
  <option ng-repeat="(portion_name, v) in cat.portions" ng-if="v == true">      
    {{portion_name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

I changed "portion" for "hours" to get simpler to explain

Comment: can you paste the html of the option fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it. [Live demo (click here.)](http://jsbin.com/qukizejedi/1/edit?html,js,output)

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div>Selected: {{selected}}</div>
  <div>Available: {{notSelectedHours()}}</div>
  <div ng-repeat="item in selects() track by $index">
    <select ng-model="selected[$index]" ng-options="hour for hour in notSelectedHours($index)"></select>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>
</div>
```

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.hours = ["0:00", "1:00", "2:00", "3:00", "4:00", "5:00"];
  $scope.selected = [];
  $scope.selects = function() {
    // automatically adjust the length of the ng-repeat to match available hours
    return new Array(Math.min($scope.hours.length, $scope.selected.length+1));
  };
  $scope.notSelectedHours = function($index) {
    return $scope.hours.filter(function(item) {
      // keep items that haven't been selected
      if ($scope.selected.indexOf(item) === -1) {
        return item;
      }
      // keep item that is selected in this repeat
      if (item === $scope.selected[$index]) {
        return item;
      }
    });
  };
  $scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.selected = [];
  };
});
```

Comment: much better than what I was going to post, +1

Comment: Thank you, it really helped me

Comment: @AndréBrandao Yeah, several tricky bits involved with this one! There may be an easier way, but this way was pretty intuitive to me.